# Read input device in C

Tags: c, macos, events, terminal, keyboard

I'm creating a 2-D platformer game in C that will run in the terminal. I need a way to register "KEY_DOWN" and "KEY_RELEASE" events. As far as I know getchar() reads from stdin and thus can not be used for registering "KEY_RELEASE" events. Neither can it be used for registering if multiple keys are being pressed down at the same time.

Is there a Mac OSX 10.10.5 C library that I can use to solve this problem? Maybe a library which reads input directly from the keyboard instead of the terminal?

Answer (score 1):

None of the potential answers are likely to be simple:

- if you are running an application in the terminal, and lacking (as OSX does) a set of system calls for reading the keyboard state directly, it won't work.
- the available sources describe non-terminal applications (mostly using Cocoa, the OSX GUI, and mostly using ObjectiveC).

Here are a few:

- [How can I detect that the Shift key has been pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268045/how-can-i-detect-that-the-shift-key-has-been-pressed)
- [Showing how to listen to all keypresses in OS X through the Cocoa API using Python and PyObjC](https://gist.github.com/ljos/3019549)
- [Listening for Global Keypresses in OSX](https://danielbeard.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/listening-for-global-keypresses-in-osx/)
- [Mouse button and keypress counter for Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/399430/mouse-button-and-keypress-counter-for-mac-os-x)
- [OSX: Detect system-wide keyDown events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752427/osx-detect-system-wide-keydown-events)

For reference (Cocoa Event Handling Guide):

- [Handling Key Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html)
- [Monitoring Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/MonitoringEvents/MonitoringEvents.html)