# how to monitor keyboard event in iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, monitor

Now I have a question is about how to observer keyboard touch in iOS.for example, if I click the 'A','B',or any key in keyboard ,how can I monitor it.I try to add an gestureRecognizer in keyboard. I can monitor it in iOS 7, iOS 9.In iOS 10, it can't work.I don't know why,so I look for another way to implement the function.

Comment: Are you trying to catch events in a text input field (an UITextField or UISearchBar)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get entered character from

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
{
Print(string)
Return true
}

Delegate method. You must need to set delegate of textfield you are entering text to.

Comment: Yes, I know.But this only works when you click some keys,such as letters. I want to monitor the voice key if I can. I don't need to know which key clicked, but I need to do something after I click the keyboard keys.

Comment: Then checkout this , i didn't try it for voice comand but it may work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268045/how-can-i-detect-that-the-shift-key-has-been-pressed