# NSView keyDown/keyUp ignores specific keys in Swift. How do I make it listen to all keys?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, keyboard, appkit

I have written this code. My problem is, the keyDown function only listens to certain keys (letters, numbers, space, characters, <kbd>Tab</kbd>.). However, it completely ignores keys like <kbd>caps lock</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>. How can I make it listen to these keys?

```
class GameClient: NSView {
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
    override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        print(event.keyCode)
    }
    override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {

    }
}
```

The answers in the suggested dupe don't fully answer my question. I don't want to see if <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> was being pressed while I was pressing <kbd>A</kbd>, I want to detect when <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> alone is pressed, for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/9268045/3141234

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I am afraid those answers might be obsolete/not fully answer my question.

Comment: How so? What's left unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

The question is how to capture a standalone shift key event, rather than detecting if shift is *being* pressed *while* another key is.  You want to do this:

```
override func flagsChanged(with event: NSEvent) {
    print(event.keyCode)
}
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    print(event.keyCode)
}
override func keyUp(with event: NSEvent) {

}
```

Comment: Is this the answer to your question? If not, do not put it in the Answer field.

Comment: @matt I DID answer the question

Comment: Ok it was the address to Alexander that confused me.

Comment: @0x10 `flagsChanged` gets called when modifiers like `shift` change, even without another key being pressed.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica That is EXACTLY the point!