# How do I check if the shift key is currently being pressed down in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, key, shift

I'm trying to check whether or not shift is being pressed when a function is run. Something like this (but obviously not this, this is just an example):

```swift
func doThisThing() {
    if Keyboard.shared.keyBeingPressed(.shift) { // < What I'm trying to figure out
        print("Doing this thing.")
    } else {
        print("You're not holding shift.")
    }
}
```

I tried looking, but all I could find was keyDown/keyUp events, which isn't practical in this case.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do such imperative things at all in SwiftUI, as far as I know... Or are you actually using AppKit and [tag:swiftui] is just a mistag?

Comment: If you _are_ using AppKit, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14774656/5133585

Comment: "all I could find was keyDown/keyUp events, which isn't practical in this case." what makes them impractical?

Comment: Maintaining state for keyDown -> Up is not practical. In AppKit you override flagsChanged in your viewcontroller and it does that state management for you. I don't know how to do it in SwiftUI though.

Answer (score 4):

```
import AppKit

public class KeyboardHelper
{
    public static var optionKeyIsDown: Bool
    {
        let flags = NSEvent.modifierFlags
        return flags.contains(.option)
    }

    public static var shiftKeyIsDown: Bool
    {
        let flags = NSEvent.modifierFlags
        return flags.contains(.shift)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I've done this sort of thing, but I seem to remember that you would need to set up an NSResponder and watch for keyDown/keyUp events. Then you'd parse the event to look for the shift key being pressed or released.

It looks like there is also a function flagsChanged that you can implement to be notified when one of the modifier keys changes state. See this SO thread:

[How can I detect that the Shift key has been pressed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268045/how-can-i-detect-that-the-shift-key-has-been-pressed)

Answer (score 0):

Look in `NSEvent.modifierFlags`:

```swift
let shiftIsPressed = NSEvent.modifierFlags.contains(.shift)
```